# Remove value from array which belongs to different class objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm new around and also I'm at very beginning of understanding objective-c language. For practice, I decided to make a program which on button press action returns string value in label from an array and change label's text. I have 3 labels so I need to get 3 different values. I don't want to get same value from array so I made do while functions. It works but I would prefer to do that through function: `removeObjectAtIndex` so I can get rid of do while loops. I made some code which there is no error but still doesn't work. here it goes:

This is implementation of class for getting random number(string) value:

```
#import "NumberGenerator.h"

@implementation NumberGenerator

- (NSMutableArray *) numberRange {
_numberRange = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                @"1",
                @"2",
                @"3",
                @"4",
                @"5",
                @"6",
                nil];
return _numberRange;
}


- (NSMutableString *) randomNumber {
int random = arc4random_uniform((int)self.numberRange.count);
return [self.numberRange objectAtIndex:random];
}
@end
```

This is header of a class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NumberGenerator : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *numberRange;

- (NSMutableString *) randomNumber;

@end
```

This is view controller class where action needs to be done. Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class NumberGenerator;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *secondNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *thirdNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NumberGenerator *numberGenerated;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NumberGenerator.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a               nib.

self.numberGenerated = [[NumberGenerator alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed {

// First number

self.firstNumber.text = [self.numberGenerated randomNumber];

NSUInteger firstVal = [self.firstNumber.text intValue] -1;
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)firstVal);
[self.numberGenerated.numberRange removeObjectAtIndex: firstVal];
NSLog(@"%@", self.numberGenerated.numberRange);

self.secondNumber.text = [self.numberGenerated randomNumber];

do {
        self.secondNumber.text = [self.numberGenerated randomNumber];
  } while (self.secondNumber.text == self.firstNumber.text);
}
@end
```

I bolded part where there is no error but still doesn't work. In this part I want to remove object from array but it still doing nothing. `NSLog` keeps printing all values. Thank you for your time.

Comment: So what have you done to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always create a new full array each time you call numberRange. I guess these are just the initial values. Add a nil check or init the values in a designated init method for `NumberGenerator`.

Either:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) numberRange {
    if (_numberRange == nil) {
        _numberRange = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3",  @"4",  @"5",  @"6", nil];
    }
    return _numberRange;
}
```

or better

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _numberRange = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3",  @"4",  @"5",  @"6", nil];
    }
    return self;
}

//Not really needed - can be removed
- (NSMutableArray *) numberRange {
    return _numberRange;
}
```